# Create dmg file on macOS 10.14 that can be opened on macOS 10.11

Tags: mojave, dmg, hdiutil

Running

```
$ hdiutil create -size <size>b <.dmg-file> -srcfolder <directory> -ov -format UDBZ
```

on macOS 10.14 creates a dmg file that can't be opened on macOS 10.11. Is there an option that creates the dmg file that way that it can be used on macOS 10.11?

Comment: Have you tried using the Disk Utility instead of the `hdiutil` command to create the dmg file?

Comment: It’s probably formatting as APFS, which I believe 10.11 can’t read (yet).

Comment: @DavidAnderson No, I haven't tried that because it must be running as a command over SSH.

Comment: If you need to transfer the files over the internet, have you considered using `rsync`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the source folder is in a APFS volume, then by default a APFS volume will be created in the dmg file. This type of volume can not be read by El Capitan. The solution would be to create a dmg file which uses JHFS+ format. The correct command you should be using is given below.

```
hdiutil create -size <size>b -fs JHFS+ <.dmg-file> -srcfolder <directory> -ov -format UDBZ
```

> Note: When testing this answer, I used the `-megabytes` option instead of the `-size` option. Also, I tested while running High Sierra instead of Mojave.